# Need to schedule Cygwin Expect Script with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: cron, cygwin, backup, cisco

I am currently in the process of implementing a backup scheme to run a Cygwin Expect Script. What I would like to do is have task scheduler open Cygwin and run an expect script called Backups.

The issue that I run into is what I believe to be either variable or path based. I have the correct user from Active directory (we'll call it AD/svc_backup) set, and I am currently trying to just see if I can get the task scheduler to open Cygwin.

So far it will only open the program if I have the run only when user is logged on radio button pressed. This will open cygwin, but not let me run any further commands and gives me an error.

For example ls gives me "bash: ls: command not found" When it asks what program I want to start, I simply point it to the shortcut on my desktop and it then fills in the path C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe . Task scheduler does not seem like the most intuitive tool IMO but if I can get it to work I will use it. I also know that cygwin can use cron as well. Would cron be a better option?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. So what the system means by the button "run only when user is logged on" radio button pressed" means is I want the script to run and I want to see it run with the local usr account. (interactive with the user)

The "run whether the user is logged in or not" button turns whatever script or program you run into a background service that has no user interactivity( you cant see it). By using the full path under the actions tab in cygwin I was able to tell it which script to run. Script path and options are like so:

C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c C:/cygwin/home/svc_p_cisco_bkp/

I have been researching the -l and -c arguments and from what I can gather the -l means list the output and the -c means run these commands. This was not listed anywhere but from what I read it is as educated of an answer as I can give. Also I tested and the script will not run correctly without these variables.

I don't see the script start when I check the "run whether the user is logged in or not" button, but I can see the backups going to my destination folder. I do see it when "run only when user is logged on" however. What I did was get the script running the way I wanted while I could see it and then choose the "run whether the user is logged in or not" radio button when I know it was working correctly.

All is up and running and after exhausting reading of pages and pages about Windows task scheduler, and I am fully automated.